How can I check that virt-manager is using QEMU and KVM?
I am using virt-manager/libvirt, which uses QEMU, which in turn makes use of KVM.
However, my understanding is that KVM only provides QEMU with hardware accelaration and, potentially QEMU could run without it. On the other hand, it is possible to have libvirt access directly KVM, without the need to use QEMU. This is obviously a gross oversimplification, but is it broadly correct?
If so, there are several possible setups:

virt-manager + QEMU + KVM
virt-manager + QEMU
virt-manager + KVM

My feeling is that number 1 is the most efficient solution, and this is what I have tried to do. But how can I check that the setup is working as I intended? Or in other words, that virt-manager is using QEMU (rather than another hypervisor) and that QEMU is using the hardware acceleration provided by KVM?
